# HttpClient simulation Login

Tags: httpclient

```
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(
            "http://bbs.elecfans.com/member.php?action=login&mod=logging&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=L55gn");
    NameValuePair name = new NameValuePair("username", userName);
    NameValuePair pass = new NameValuePair("password", password);
    NameValuePair __VIEWSTATE = new NameValuePair(
            "__VIEWSTATE",
            "loginAddr");
    NameValuePair btnLoginx = new NameValuePair("btnLogin.x", "0");
    NameValuePair btnLoginy = new NameValuePair("btnLogin.y", "5");
    post.setRequestBody(new NameValuePair[] { name, pass, __VIEWSTATE,
            btnLoginx, btnLoginy });
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    post.releaseConnection();
```

tks

Comment: is Visit the website address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to analyze this log on address to find the correct login address and The HttpClient Head to the scrambling of data to.